# MDX order doesn't work

Tags: mdx

I'm using the AdventureWorks Cube and MS SQL 2017 to learn MDX.
I'd like to return the top five selling subcategories of products, based on Internet Sales Amount:

```
SELECT Subset

(Order

    ([Product].[Product Categories].[SubCategory].members

    ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]

    ,DESC

    )

    ,0

    ,5

)
ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

The returned results are not sorted properly. Is there anything I did wrong?

Road Bikes  Mountain Bikes  Touring Bikes   Tires and Tubes Helmets

$29,358,206.96  $26,492,684.38  $10,451,490.22  $925.21 $258,712.93

I also tried BDESC, seems to get the same result.

Answer (score 3):

This query will help explain what happened. It was sorting correctly, but then it was displaying the default measure on the screen since you didn't specify the measure to display, only the measure to sort by:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], [Measures].DefaultMember} on 0,
Subset
(Order
    ([Product].[Product Categories].[SubCategory].members
    ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ,DESC
    )
    ,0
    ,5
)
ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

I would recommend using that query but removing `[Measures].DefaultMember` and you should get the results you expect.

Comment: Hi Thanks! I'll test it at home and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You want the TOPCOUNT MDX function

```
SELECT
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON COLUMNS
,   TOPCOUNT([Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory].MEMBERS,5,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]) ON ROWS
FROM
[Adventure Works]
```

Comment: Hi Thanks! I'll test it at home and get back to you. BTW is there a reason that Order doesn't work? Because I'm taking the tutorial from MSDN.